# Empirical parameters in rtruncnorm

Tags: r

This is about random number generation with rtruncnorm. While specifying its parameters, should the mean and standard deviation refer to the parent normal distribution as empirical parameters or to the current truncated normal distribution from which sampling is to be done?

Comment: is this from the `truncnorm` package?

Comment: Yes. the "truncnorm" package

Comment: It will be the parent distribution e.g. try `f <- rtruncnorm(10000, a=0, b=Inf, mean=0, sd=1)`. Using `hist` and `mean` becomes apparent

Comment: presumably you're also the author of [this issue](https://github.com/olafmersmann/truncnorm/issues/4)?  It would be good to cross-link that.  You could probably figure this out by some simulation tests ...

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. Thank you, Jonny Phelps and Ben Bolker.